# Node parse raw string into query params

Tags: node.js, query-string

string:

```
?utm_campaign=My+Campaign+Name&amp;utm_medium=email
```

I want to turn this into an object:

```
{    
  utm_campaign: "My Campaign Name",
  utm_medium: "email"
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to accomplish this with the `querystring` module but can't seem to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `&amp;`. It should be `&` otherwise it is treated as a regular character and not the special character separating query parameters.